# Definite integral with Jacobi weight function

Tags: integration

I want to use the Quadpack subroutine [dqaws](http://www.netlib.org/quadpack/dqaws.f) to calculate an approximation of a definite integral of $f(x)w(x)$ with the Jacobi weight function $w(x) = (1-x)^\alpha(1+x)^\beta$.

However the option of `dqaws` that comes closest to my weight function is $w'(x) = (x-1)^\alpha(1-x)^\beta$.

So my question is: Can I transform $w'(x)$ to $w(x)$?